# How to enable remote audio in KVM VM via rdp

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, kvm-switch

I have a Windows 10 VM running in KVM, & when I connect via RDP, even though I have remote audio enabled in the RDP client, I still get an error complaining about there being no audio hardware installed.

How can I get this to work?

Screenshots:

https://imgur.com/NPe7lrA

https://imgur.com/y4AUYZ0

Comment: To start a the beginning, have you checked the Windows Device Manager and made sure all the drivers are good?  I have seen generic audio drivers not cut it before.  It is best to get the manufacturer's drivers if possible.

Comment: There's no audio device in device manager. I need to use rdp to forward audio to the machine I'm connecting from, but there's no audio device- that's the problem.